# Kerberos authentication without JAAS?

Tags: java, kerberos, jaas

Is it possible to authenticate a user/password using Kerberos but without using JAAS?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid JAAS? The `KerberosLoginModule` should be used which JAAS.

Comment: I ended up sticking with JAAS.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, See Use of JavaTM GSS-API for Secure Message Exchanges Without JAAS Programming at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/jgss/tutorials/BasicClientServer.html